# Boomi / Groovy - Calculate YTD hours based on custom date

Tags: groovy, integration, groovy-console, boomi

Using Dell Boomi, I'm pulling in a report for an integration I'm working on.  This integration requires YTD hours, but starting on July 1st.

In order to do this, I know that I need to pull in all the data (to be safe) for current and previous year in order to have the full data set, but am unsure of what I need to do in order to calculate the hours and that the hours reset every July 1st automatically.  I'm assuming that I will need either a custom map function to do many things or use a groovy script.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what is you problem/question. a code, input data , and expected output could help to understand. please edit your question. if this question not about groovy code - please remove `groovy` related tags.

Comment: If you post the input and output document I can assist ( assuming you want a Boomi groovy script to solve the problem )

Comment: @daggett, What I'm trying to do, is to sum all the hours for an individual from July 1st until June 30th the following year.  Once July 1st of the following year (2022 in this case) is upon us, then the number of hours gets reset and we begin adding the number of hours anew.  I need to write the code, so that it's future proof (no need to adjust the code every year).

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli, Per your request, I've loaded a sample of expected input doc (Table 1) and Output doc (Table 2).  Again, every July 1st, hours get reset, so YTD hours is Jul 1 to June 30th NOT Jan 1 to Dec 31st...

Comment: Ok got I’ll try and build and sample process that transforms the data with a Groovy script shape